# Problem while changing from field to field in a Formulary automated with Autohotkey

Tags: microsoft-forms

I've automated filling a formulary developed with Microsoft Forms but sometimes it works and sometimes don't.

Originally changing from one input field to another just requires sending a TAB. I do that in Autohotkey with the command:

```
    Send , {TAB}
```

What I've found is that sometimes the "area" of a question can be selected, and sometimes it does not.

When the area of a question can be selected, I must send two TABs to change from the current input filed to the next one:

```
    Send , {TAB 2}
```

I'm currently using Microsoft Edge, but I've also used Firefox and Google Chrome and the behavior is the same. It's funny that the first time I tried Firefox, or Chrome the question areas are not selectable but after refreshing the form (F5) the question areas become selectable.

I've also tried closing the browser and even turning my computer off and restarting it again.

**But the behavior is always the same: ** Sometimes the question areas are selectable and sometimes don't.

I don't know if it is a browser configuration (I think not because different browsers exhibit the same behavior).
Even, it could be the form rendering from Microsoft or any other thing I really don't know.

I just don't want to have two Autohotkey programs for filling the same form, one used when question areas are selectable and other for when question areas are not selectable.

So, any help would be appreciated.

Kind regards,

J.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when you are logged in your Microsoft 365 account then question areas are selectable and when you are logged out, they are not.

So, to avoid question areas to be selectable (and need an additional tab in autohotkey) you just need to be logged off from you Microsoft 365 account and that's all.

So, to fill my form automatically I log off from my Microsoft 365 account and run my autohotkey script and it fills the form correctly.

Seems odd, but it is working for me, and this is better than having two scripts for the same Microsoft Form.

J.